# IE Forces a Horizontal Scrollbar in a dojo AccordionPane

Tags: javascript, dojo, scrollbar, accordion

HI all,

I have and issue that looks like it's due to IE's box model bug, but I'm not quite sure how to solve it in dojo.

I have a ContentPane which I put into a typical AccordionContainer, and static content is palced in the ContentPane. On all other browsers, if the content  in the ContentPane overflows the bottom, a vertical scrollbar appears as we would expect. However, in IE, a horizontal scrollbar appears as well when the vertical scrollbar appears.

It seems evident that the ContentPane in IE is not taking the size of the vertical scrollbars into account, so when they show up, it is adding a horizontal scrollbar to accomodate them.

I would like a horizontal scrollbar to appear when it's appropriate, not simply because a vertical scrollbar was added.

Any idea how to accomplish this cleanly in dojo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try playing with overflow, overflow-x and overflow-y in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow-x:auto and overflow-y:hidden in your contentpane.